# header function no esta trabajando

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola tengo un código de votaciones donde una vez realizas la votación el sistema añade la respuesta a la base de datos, eso parte esta funcionando aunque no se ve, Antes realizabas la votación te daba el mensaje si habías votado o no y se quedaba en la página de home.php diciendo que ya habías votado, pero en estos momentos no se que hice que ya no muestra el mensaje de que ya hizo la votación y la página se vuelve en blanco. Volví a subir todos los archivos nuevamente al servidor y aun sigue haciendo lo mismo, es como si el header no funcionara ya que en vez de ir o quedarse en home.php se va a submit_ballot.php.

Este es parte del código que se encuentra en home donde te permite votar. (antes de este código esta la validación si ya votaste o no).

```
<!-- Voting Ballot Donde se ven los candidatos y puedes votar-->
                            <form method="POST" id="ballotForm" action="submit_ballot.php">
                            
                                <?php
                                    include 'includes/slugify.php';
                                    

                                    $candidate = '';
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM positions ORDER BY priority ASC";
                                    $query = $conn->query($sql);
                                    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                                        $sql = "Select C.id, C.credentials, C.firstname, C.lastname from candidates C LEFT JOIN positions P ON P.priority = C.position_id                                             GROUP BY C.credentials ORDER by C.credentials ASC";
                                        $cquery = $conn->query($sql);
                                        while($crow = $cquery->fetch_assoc()){
                                            $slug = slugify($row['description']);
                                            $checked = '';
                                            if(isset($_SESSION['post'][$slug])){
                                                $value = $_SESSION['post'][$slug];

                                                if(is_array($value)){
                                                    foreach($value as $val){
                                                        if($val == $crow['id']){
                                                            $checked = 'checked';
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    if($value == $crow['id']){
                                                        $checked = 'checked';
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            $input = ($row['max_vote'] > 1) ? 
                                            '<input type="checkbox" class="flat-red '.$slug.'" name="'.$slug."[]".'" value="'.$crow['id'].'" '.$checked.'>' : 
                                            '<input type="radio" class="flat-red '.$slug.'" name="'.slugify($row['description']).'" value="'.$crow['id'].'"                                                         '.$checked.'>';
                                            
                                            $candidate .= '
                                                <li>
                                                    '.$input.'
                                        <i class="fa fa
                                        ="100px" class="clist"><span class="cname clist">'.$crow['credentials'].' '.$crow['firstname'].' '.$crow['lastname'].'</span>
                                                </li>
                                            ';
                                        }
                                        
                                        $instruct = ($row['max_vote'] > 1) ? 'You may select up to '.$row['max_vote'].' candidates' : 'Selecciona un candidato';
                                        echo '
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                    <div class="box box-solid" id="'.$row['id'].'">
                                                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                                                                <br><br>
                                                            <h3 class="box-title"><b>'.$row['description'].'</b></h3>
                                                        <div class="box-body">
                                                        <p>'.$instruct.'
                                                                <span class="pull-right">
                                                                    <button onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">Actualizar Página</button>
                                                                </span>
                                                                <th class="hidden"></th>
                                                            </p>
                                                            <div id="candidate_list">
                                                                <ul>
                                                                    '.$candidate.'
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </div>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        ';

                                        $candidate = '';
                                    }   

                                ?>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" name="vote"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Someter</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <!-- End Voting Ballot -->
```

Este es el código completo de submit_ballot.php yo nunca edité este código en realidad no se que hice o que pasó

```
<?php
    include 'includes/session.php';
    include 'includes/slugify.php';

    if(isset($_POST['vote'])){
        if(count($_POST) == 1){
            $_SESSION['error'][] = 'Votar por un candidato';
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM positions";
            $query = $conn->query($sql);
            $error = false;
            $sql_array = array();
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                $position = slugify($row['description']);
                $pos_id = $row['id'];
                if(isset($_POST[$position])){
                    if($row['max_vote'] > 1){
                        if(count($_POST[$position]) > $row['max_vote']){
                            $error = true;
                            $_SESSION['error'][] = 'Solo puedes votar por '.$row['max_vote'].' candidatos para '.$row['description'];
                        }
                        else{
                            foreach($_POST[$position] as $key => $values){
                                $sql_array[] = "INSERT INTO votes (voters_id, candidate_id, position_id) VALUES ('".$voter['id']."', '$values', '$pos_id')";
                            }

                        }
                        
                    }
                    else{
                        $candidate = $_POST[$position];
                        $sql_array[] = "INSERT INTO votes (voters_id, candidate_id, position_id) VALUES ('".$voter['id']."', '$candidate', '$pos_id')";
                    }

                }
                
            }

            if(!$error){
                foreach($sql_array as $sql_row){
                    $conn->query($sql_row);
                }

                unset($_SESSION['post']);
                $_SESSION['success'] = 'Balota sometida';
                
            }

        }

    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['error'][] = 'Seleccionar 1 candidato';
        
    }
    header('location: home.php');
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que verifica si se ha votado o no? ¿Te has planteado en verificar eso previamente, antes de que el usuario siquiera intente votar? Me explico: si tú verificas digamos por un ID que el usuario tal votó o no, lo propio sería verificar eso de antemano, no agotar todo un proceso, como puede ser llenar un formulario etc, para luego verificarlo, haciendo perder tiempo a todo el mundo y dilapidando recursos.